# Visual Studio 2010 - System.Data.Services acting strange

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010, I'm building a Silverlight C# application. I'm attempting to use an [IRequestHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.irequesthandler.aspx) in order to build a custom SOAP request.

I've included the appropriate reference (System.Data.Services), and the appropriate namespace. (I get no error on the namespace).

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Services;               
using System.Data.Services.Client;        <---- Shouldn't need these, added 
using System.Data.Services.Common;        <----    in desperation.

namespace HurricaneMaps
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Let's make a manual request via SOAP - simple object access protocol
            IRequestHandler irh;
        }
    }
}
```

When compiling, I get a missing reference/bad namespace for IRequestHandler... I'm at my wits end! Is there something I'm missing, or is this an error with VS? I've tried making a new project under different versions, but no luck.

In fact, nothing from System.Data.Service ([MSDN - System.Data.Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.aspx)) works for me... I should include a screenshot showing that it is in my references, but you'll have to trust me.. anyone encounter a similar issue?

Comment: are you including the right reference?

Comment: as far as I can read from the MSDN-Docs this Type/Assembly/Namespace is not supported in Silverlight (you can normaly choose this by clicking "other Versions" - if you cannot find Silverlight in the supported Frameworks you might be out of luck)

Comment: .NET 4.0 supports: "Windows 7, Windows Vista SP1 or later, Windows XP SP3, Windows Server 2008 (Server Core not supported), Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core supported with SP1 or later), Windows Server 2003 SP2" and .NET 3.5 supports "Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP SP2, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2003" - no silverlight sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IRequestHandler and therefore System.Data.Services is not part if Silverlight.. only System.Data.Services.Client is..

But you may achieve what you want by using sth.like: HttpWebRequest.Create(xyz)

Comment: I've decided to use REST instead of SOAP, they are both supported on the server.